# How to switch to new Activity from menu?

Tags: android, menu, android-activity, contextmenu, android-intent

I have a menu and would like to open a new Activity when the user clicks on the menu item:

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.add_symbol:
           System.out.println("ADD SYMBOL CLICKED!");
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.getContext(), AddStocksActivity.class);
           startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

I'm not sure how to create my Intent properly

Compiler Error:

```
The method getContext() is undefined for the type Main
```

Comment: What happens with the code you have?  Usually you can use "this" as the context for your itnent.

Comment: The method getContext() is undefined for the type Main

Comment: Are you not using eclipse? You should get an error on that line in the eclipse editor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `Main` extends `Activity` (which extends `Context`), you can do:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AddStocksActivity.class)
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, if you have to do this in an anonymous inner class you can follow my answer. Or you can do `MyActivity.this`

Answer (score 2):

this is what I do

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.options_menu, menu);

    MenuItem item1 = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_a);
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, A.class);
    item1.setIntent(intent1);

    MenuItem item2 = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_b);
    Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, B.class);
    item2.setIntent(intent2);
```

}

hope it helps

Comment: you can use YourClassName.this instead of just this

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.getContext()` to `this.getApplicationContext()`

You are trying to call a method that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity class do

```
Context mContext;
```

In your onCreate() do

```
mContext = this
```

then in your Options thing, do

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this.getContext(), AddStocksActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AddStocksActivity.class);
```

or

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AddStocksActivity.class)
```