# Start an activity with an intent from another activity's ContextMenu

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent, contextmenu

I don't know how to start an `Intent` to call another activity from my `ContextMenu`. I have the following code:

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.profile);
    Button button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        registerForContextMenu(button5);
    //...code...//

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Profile Options");
        menu.add(0,v.getId(),0, "Header");
        menu.add(0,v.getId(),0, "Header");

**This is where my Intent is ** Intent intent = new Intent (CustomizeActivity2.this, CustomizeActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    public boolean OnContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(item.getTitle()=="Edite Profile"){

            function1(item.getItemId());
            }

        else {return false;}
        return true;
    }

    public void function1(int id){
        Toast.makeText(this,"Edit Profile Called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
    }
```

I want to start another activity when I'm clicking the item from my `ContextMenu`, where I have some settings.

Comment: Oh look, in the Related column there is [How to switch to new Activity from menu?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3587761/how-to-switch-to-new-activity-from-menu)  Over there -->

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some errors in your code. The `onCreateContextMenu` method where your `ContextMenu` is built:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Profile Options");
        menu.add(0, 1000, 0, "Header1"); // give your menus distinct ids!!!
        menu.add(0, 1001, 0, "Header2");
}
```

and the callback called when the user selects one of the options from the `ContextMenu` and starts a new activity:

```
//the correct callback name starts with o and not O
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   switch (item.getItemId()) {
   case 1000:
       //first ContextMenu option I picked this to start the  new activity
       Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivityName.this, OtherActivityName.class);
       startActivity(i);
   break; 
   case 1001:
      //stuff for option 2 of the ContextMenu
   break;
   }
   return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To Start an activity any-where in the code you need to create a new intent, setting target component to target activity class, then invoke startActivity method with this intent parameter.

Comment: thank you very much, but in my context code, i've tried to create a new Intent, but my other Activity simply doesn't start. This is my code and and where i put it: 'public boolean OnContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 if(item.getTitle()=="Edite Profile"){
           **Intent intent = new Intent (this, AnotherActivity.class); startActivity(intent);**
  function1(item.getItemId());
 }'   Thanks in advance

Comment: @Johannes I don't think you can use 'this' when specifying the *from* variable because you're inside the OnContextItemSelected. Try using [ActivityName].this <-- e.g Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, AnotherActivity.class);

Comment: @Gophermofur i've tried this, but still nothing happens :( . My problem is i don't know where should i put the intent from a specific Item from ContextMenu to open my other class. Based on my code above.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter where you put it, as long as you are calling it correctly. What is the name of your activity (the one posted above)? Can you show us the intent declaration with the change I suggested above? I just want to see if we're on the same page.

Comment: @Gophermofur this is my Code: 'public boolean OnContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
 if(item.getTitle()=="Edite Profile"){
  
  Intent intent = new Intent (CustomizeActivity2.this, CustomizeActivity.class);
  startActivity(intent);

  function1(item.getItemId());
  }'

Comment: That looks right, assuming you have your activities in the correct order. My other thought is that you haven't defined the other activity in your manifest (see my answer)

Comment: Now, my other Activity starts, but, unfortunately starts right after the Context Menu Opens (after holding long pressed the button). I want to open the other activity when i select one item from my Context Menu. this is actually my problem, and don't know where should i place the Intent. See my Edited Code where the Intent is. Thanks Guys !

Answer (score 0):

```
// in my Util.java:
static void switchActivity(Activity from, Class<?> to) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(from, to);
    from.startActivity(intent);
    from.finish(); // only do this if you want to close the current activity
}

// in your context menu:
Util.switchActivity(this, AnotherActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have declared the 2nd activity (the one you are calling) in the Manifest. You won't get a compile error, but Android can't launch an activity that hasn't been defined in the manifest, even if it is in your current package/apk.

If you want, show us what your manifest.xml file contains and we'll have a better idea if anything there needs to change.

Edit: Make sure you see something like this in your manifest

```
<activity android:name=".CustomizeActivity" />
```